# How do I find the north and south bound of a particular state in USA

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geocoder

I am trying to implement the restriction view of google maps API.

Not able to find the north and south coordinates of the same.

Is there any API for it ?

Comment: Geocode the state.  Use the bounds in the response.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start) to get the state's bounds. There's a handy geocoder tool [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#place_id%3DChIJPV4oX_65j4ARVW8IJ6IJUYs).

Take a look at this working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dktaq1en/1/) based off of Google's example for demonstration of a map restricted to California state bounds. Code below:

```
var map;
var CALIFORNIA_BOUNDS = {
  north: 42.009517,
  south: 32.528832,
  west: -124.482003,
  east: -114.131211
};
var CALIFORNIA = {
  lat: 36.778261,
  lng: -119.417932
};

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: CALIFORNIA,
    restriction: {
      latLngBounds: CALIFORNIA_BOUNDS,
      strictBounds: false, // or true if you want
    },
    zoom: 7,
  });
}
```

Hope this helps!